# How can I prove that $\Vert \int _Xfd\mu \Vert \leq \int _X\Vert f\Vert d\mu $?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, inequality

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu )$ be measure space. Denote by $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ the set of the matrix $m\times n$. Suppose that $f:X\to \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is a function whose coordinates are integrable. Define $\int _Xfd\mu \in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ such that the element $ij$ of this matrix is the integration of the coordinate $ij$ of $f$. **My question is:** how can I prove that $\Vert \int _Xfd\mu \Vert \leq \int _X\Vert f\Vert d\mu $ in which $\Vert \cdot \Vert $ is the norm defined by $\Vert A\Vert :=\sqrt{\text{tr}(A^TA)}$ for all $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.

---

Unfortunately I didn't nothing worth mentioning.

---

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: For simple functions, this is just triangle inequality. Now approximate $f$ by a sequence of simple functions to obtain the general result.

Comment: ^ also it is irrelevant which norm you use. This inequality is true for all of them. This is essentially adding steroids to the usual triangle inequality of norms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the approach to this problem is to prove the result for simple functions and then to extend the result to integrable functions. Let $\phi$ be a simple function on $(X, \Sigma , \mu )$, so that $\phi = \sum_{k=1}^{\ell}\chi_{A_{k}}c_{k}$ for some measurable subsets of finite measure $A_{1}, \ldots , A_{\ell}$ and $c_{1}, \ldots , c_{\ell}\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. Then

$$\int_{X} \phi \, {\rm d}\mu = \sum_{k=1}^{\ell}\mu (A_{k})c_{k},$$

and so

$$\left\| \int_{X} \phi \, {\rm d}\mu \right\| \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\ell}\mu (A_{k})\|c_{k}\| = \int_{X}\|\phi\|_{\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}} \, {\rm d}\mu ,$$

where $\|\phi\|_{\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}}$ denotes the function mapping from $X$ into $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ given by $\|\phi\|_{\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}}(x) := \|\phi (x)\|_{\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}}$.

For the general case, note that as $f$ is (Bochner-) integrable, there is a sequence $(\phi_{k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ of simple functions which converge almost everywhere to $f$ such that

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \int_{X} \|\phi_{k} - f\|_{\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}} \, {\rm d}\mu = 0.$$

It also follows that the sequence $(\| \phi_{k} \|_{\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ form a sequence of real-valued simple functions which converge almost everywhere to $\|f\|_{\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}}$. Consequently, it can be shown that $\|f\|$ is also integrable, and so

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \int_{X} \phi_{k} \, {\rm d}\mu = \int_{X} f \, {\rm d}\mu$$

and

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \int_{X} \|\phi_{k}\|_{\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}} \, {\rm d}\mu = \int_{X} \|f\|_{\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}} \, {\rm d}\mu .$$

Then it follows that

$$\left\| \int_{X}f \, {\rm d}\mu \right\| = \lim_{k\to\infty} \left\| \int_{X} \phi_{k} \, {\rm d}\mu \right\| \leq \lim_{k\to\infty} \int_{X} \|\phi_{k}\|_{\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}} \, {\rm d}\mu = \int_{X} \|f\|_{\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}} \, {\rm d}\mu .$$

This obtains the desired result.